# Packaged Python Wheel unable to import packages in the same directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, release, pypi

Using Python 3.5

I have this structure in place

```
someCode/
   someCode/
       A.py 
       __init__.py
       setup.py
       README.md
       LICENSE
       MANIFEST.rst
       someSubDir/
          B.py
          __init__.py
```

A.py imports some class of B.py using

```
from someSubDir.B import someClass
```

This works perfectly when I run my python scripts.

I packaged this using wheel and installed the wheel dist into a different conda environment. Here lies the issue 
When I try to import the module using

```
import someCode.A as A 
ImportError: No module named 'someSubDir.B'
```

It seems python interpreter is looking for a module named someSubDir in the environment but I want it to look within someCode module to figure that out.

Where am I going wrong here?

UPDATE 
This is what my setup.py looks like

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

ver = "9.9.9"
with open("README.md", mode='r') as f:
    long_description = f.read()


setup(
   name='someCode',
   version=ver,
   url='https://github.com/something',
   description='something else',
   long_description=long_description,
   license='GNU',
   author='someone',
   author_email='something@gmail.com',
   classifiers=[
       "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
       "Intended Audience :: Developers",
       "Topic :: Software Development",
       "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License (GPL)",
       "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5",
       ],
   keywords='operations',
   packages=find_packages(), 
   install_requires=[],
   python_requires='~=3.5'
)
```

Comment: Verify that `someSubDir/B.py` is installed. Show us your `setup.py`.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Added setup.py to the original question

Comment: Figured it out. Posted the answer below. Thanks for your help. It got me thinking more

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out 
Python Interpreter needs to know that B.py needs to be imported from within SomeCode/

Modified import in A.py to relative import

```
from .someSubDir.B import someClass
```

Works like a charm once the built distribution is deployed and aforementioned imports are tried out